# How to reset auto increment column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have two columns, one of them is `t1` (`int` type) that is auto increment, and the other column is `t2` (`char` type)

I try to execute insert query

```
INSERT into test(t2) values('test1');
INSERT into test(t2) values('test2');
INSERT into test(t2) values('test3');
```

look at the result is below

```
t1 | t2
----------
 1 | test1
 2 | test2
 3 | test3
```

I want to write a trigger that if I try to execute delete query, auto increment is reset

```
Delete from t1 
where t1 = 2;
```

I want a trigger that returns this result:

```
t1 | t2
----------
 1 | test1
 2 | test3
```

Please let me know best way!

I'm waiting for your answer

Thanks

Comment: Autoidentity doesn't fits well into scenario you've described because you can't modify values of column having autoidentity. It's better to remove autoidentity from `t1` column and recalculate its values on insert/delete with triggers.

Comment: It's a bad plan. if you care about the numerical value of identity columns, you're using them wrong. It does seem like a simple `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1)` included when you *select* this data would give you the results without having to fiddle about with re-assigning column values.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Find the highest number in the auto increment field
To find the highest number, run the following SQL command:

```
SELECT MAX( `column` ) FROM `table` ;
 Replace 'column' with the name of the auto incrementing column. Replace    table with the name of the table.
```

Reset the auto increment field
The next step is to take the number that you get from the first command and auto increment from there. So add one to that number and run the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` AUTO_INCREMENT = number;
 Replacing 'number' with the result of the previous command plus one and      replacing table with the table name.
```

If you deleted all the rows in the table, then you could run the alter table command and reset it to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query to reset the number of your Auto Increment

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = value;
```

NOTE: The auto increment value should be greater than or equal to maximum value of the auto-increment column.

You can check more [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-reset-auto-increment)

Comment: This does not work on SQL server. The reference you gave was for MySQL